# Behaviour difference between ON DUPLICATE UPDATE and UPDATE

Tags: sql, mariadb

Some back story:

Currently I am using MariaDB 10.5 in my application and was trying out some query's. What a notice was some behaviour difference for calling a AFTER UPDATE trigger between a normal UPDATE and a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

What is the reason that the trigger is called when you are using a UPDATE even when the given data is exactly the same. But if you try a insert (with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) with the same data that is already existing it won't call the trigger?

Is there a chance that this behaviour will change in the future with a newer version?

Example:

DB columns: [key] id, username

DB data: 1, nico

Query that triggers update event:

`UPDATE account SET id=1, username='nico'`

Query that won't trigger event:

`INSERT INTO account VALUES (1, 'nico') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='nico'`

Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f5e2d3e0a15bc10da0c7574a4ab6e302

Comment: Not seeing the same thing, based on [this DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=3708e706574c3262f27892422f70a8cf) with v10.5.13. Get two updates logged, one for a regular update, and another from an ODK update.

Comment: It is only happening when updating with same data so do a update with tester and not tester1 or tester2. This is a situation that won't happen often but is possible in my environment. The problem is not that the trigger is called or is not called the problem is that it is different between the methods.

Comment: Changed your fiddle to the situation I mean: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f5e2d3e0a15bc10da0c7574a4ab6e302